# How to remove repetitive chars in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a file that contains words with repetitive chars, like:

- boooody
- Steveeen
- uuuuuuser
- etccccc

In Javascript(used on nodejs), how do i remove that extra chars so i get `body`, `user` etc.?

Comment: What do you want to do with *valid* duplicated letters, such as the one in the word "letters"?

Comment: Do you also want to squeeze non-printing characters?

Comment: oh, forgot to mention, i need only repetitive alphanumerics removed, not comas, dots, spaces etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple regex is good for such thing.

```
"boooody".replace(/(\w)\1+/g, "$1");
// "body"
```

Comment: `\w` will only match letters. not any "chars"

Comment: @BorisGuéry yes. But OP emphasizes on alphanumerics

Comment: wow, that easy? I knew my loop solution is a expression of irrationality. :) Thank you!

Comment: @StevenBell you need at lest 10 reputation. Do contribute to the SO community and you'll get some reps.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
str.replace(/(.)\1{1,}/g, "$1");
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know, brainfart. I think a backreference should work though.

Comment: Seems OK. +1 for a smart solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
var words = [
    'boooody',
    'Steveeen',
    'uuuuuuser',
    'etccccc'
];

for (var i = 0, l = words.length; i < l; ++i) {
    var word = words[i].replace(/[^\w\s]|(.)(?=\1)/gi, ""); 
}
```

[Runnable example](http://jsfiddle.net/nFfND/) on JSFiddle
​